# Why does php artisan migrate fresh --seed is not working properly

Tags: laravel

Hi developers i have question regarding on **php artisan migrate:refresh --seed** VS **php artisan db:seed** I just wanted to ask because I have problem on php artisan migrate:refresh --seed, however when I use the php artisan db::seed it works properly

Now the data that I Created on my seeder is not seeding to the tables. I don't know why where the problem came from

> Seeding: VehicleModelsSeeder
>
> Seeded:  VehicleModelsSeeder (0 seconds)

Here is my vehicle model seeder class

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Vehicle;
use App\VehicleModel;

class VehicleModelsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //

        $vehicles = Vehicle::all();
        foreach($vehicles as $vehicles_data) {
            VehicleModel::forceCreate([
                'name' => Str::random(5),
                'vehicle_id' => $vehicles_data->id
            ]);

        }
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `db:seed` command runs the `Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder` class.

There is two solutions:

**1. You need to call your additional seeder(s) in the default seeder's run method.**

`database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            VehicleModelsSeeder::class
        ]);
    }
```

Then:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

**2. You can specify which seeder you want to run with the `--class` flag, but in this case you need to run the `refresh` and the `migrate` commands separately:**

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan db:seed --class:VehicleModelsSeeder
```

More info: [Laravel database seeding documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding)